# How to establish Remote Console Access for Ubuntu Server without GUI (Desktop Enviroment)?

Tags: remote-access, remote-server, remote-control

I have an Ubuntu server run on 21.10 version without Gui. Sometime I would access its console remotely to see some output values. I don't want install any Desktop Enviroment libraries like VNC, it should be like Digital Ocean Droplet Web Console or Gitlab terminal CI Running Jobs. I don't know any tool or software play a role like that.
[image: Ci gitlab termial]